# Looking for a free alternative to ProjectPlace

Tags: collaboration

Does anyone know of a good free alternative to [Project Place](http://www.projectplace.com/)?

Comment: I think that you should add link to `Project Place` to your question.

Comment: ... or at least explain what it does and what functionality you need.

Comment: I linked it. Feel free to correct me if I got the wrong website, JL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Project 2 Manage](http://www.project2manage.com/).

> Project2Manage is a free hosted project management solution that virtually anyone can use.
>
> - It’s FREE!!!
> - Helps keep projects organized
> - Assign multiple levels of permission to different clients & users
> - Manage your projects from anywhere
> - Manage unlimited projects
> - Post Messages to keep everyone up to date
> - Manage Tasks with To-Do Lists
> - Create Milestones to stay on task
> - Collaborative writing with Spot2Jot

Is that what are you searching for?

Comment: It's not free! It's $6.95 and up per month. See [price list](http://www.project2manage.com/account/signup/).

Answer (score 1):

There is a free version of [basecamp](http://www.basecamphq.com) that allows only a few developers to use the software. It is limited to just one project and doesn't have all the bells and whistles as other software, but it works. I'm not sure if it will replace Project Place, however, because I have never used Project Place.

Hopefully it has the same features. If not, then good luck in your search.

Comment: Looks like they've removed their free offering

Answer (score 1):

Check out [http://www.MinaProjekt.se](http://join.minaprojekt.se), a Swedish collaboration site without any charge. Kindly hosted so no installation required. You are up and running with your project in no time. Support many types of online projects. Welcome to try out today!

Answer (score 1):

you can check out projectpier.org or redmine.org for good alternatives